# Symfony 2.8 how to upload images to remote server using form fileType field

Tags: symfony, upload

I want to upload images to remote server, I read symfony document about How to Upload Files. While that document just says save images to local server not remote server.I want to know how to upload images to remote server using form fileType field.

Answer (score 1):

The form type should not be responsible of anything related to the management of your file. If the form is valid, do the job by handling the `UploadedFile` object the way you want to push your file through a ftp service or whatever.